# how to create a lotus notes view that shows mails from last two days?

Tags: lotus-notes

How do I create a view in Lotus Notes that shows recent mails, say mails received in last two days? My naive attempt was to Create a view with Simple Search `date created is in the last 2 days`. While this pulls in newer mails it does not seem to clear out old mails. Which means the view contains all mails received since two days before the view was created.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried something like this:

```
@Created > @Adjust( @Today; 0; 0; -2; 0; 0; 0 )
```

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a good way to do this unless you want to do some coding.
You should find that pressing Shift-F9 on the keyboard when you have that view open will remove older mails from that view, though this may be affected by the access controls on your mail file.

More information on shortcuts to update view contents:
- F9 refreshes the current view, updating what you see on-screen from the current view index. I believe F5 also does this from Notes 8.0 onwards.
- Shift-F9 rebuilds the current view index from scratch.
- Ctrl-Shift-F9 rebuilds all views in the current database (mail file, or any other Notes application). This can be very slow in large databases.